# want add new tab query using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am using the following code which is opening url in the same page, but I want to open in a new tab. how to achieve it.

```
$("#problemtype").change(function() {
    $(".for_print").toggle($(this).val() == 'Printer Problem').attr('href',$(this).val());
});
```

Comment: `window.open($(this).val(), '_blank');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
$("#problemtype").change(function() {
  $(".for_print").toggle($(this).val() == 'Printer Problem').attr({'href':$(this).val(),'target':'_blank'});
});
```

See here how to set multiple attributes in jquery http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_html_attr_set_pairs

Comment: @Atif glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.selector').attr('target', '_blank');
```

It will add target attribute to value _blank to the selected tag, and the link will open in new tab.

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.open()` method for this.

```
var win = window.open('http://stackoverflow.com/', '_blank');
if (win) {
    //Browser has allowed it to be opened
    win.focus();
} else {
    //Browser has blocked it
    alert('Please allow popups for this website');
}
```